# How to stop django management command after a time period using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, django, time, multiprocessing

I have to run a python command function in the following manner:

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
        def add_arguments(self, parser):
                parser.add_argument('plant', type=int)
                parser.add_argument('month', type=int)
        def handle(self,*args,**options):
                func= Library_Class()
                plants= options.get('plant')
                month= options.get('month')
                for plant in plants:
                        result= func.library_function(plant,month)
                return
```

This code gives arguments to the library function which in turn returns the required output.
I want to stop this command function after **100 seconds** of run time. How Do I use multiprocessing to call the library function as a process and terminate the program in 100 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and came up with this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError

from django.core.management import BaseCommand


def do_da_thing(plants, month):
    for plant in plants:
        result= func.library_function(plant, month)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('plant', type=int)
        parser.add_argument('month', type=int)
    def handle(self,*args,**options):
        func= Library_Class()
        plants= options.get('plant')
        date= options.get('month')
        with Pool(processes=1) as pool:
            res = pool.apply_async(do_da_thing, (plants, month))
            try:
                # block for 100 sec or until we get a reply
                result = res.get(timeout=100)
            except TimeoutError:
                self.stdout.write("took longer than 100 seconds")
        return
```

I also haven't tested it at all.

Comment: I have edited the code. The undefined variables were my mistake

Comment: @AyushSinha - updated to reflect your changes

Comment: The object of the library class 'func' cannot be used directly in the function do_da_thing()

Comment: @AyushSinha - that's your code... I copied from what you had.  I have no idea what a `func.library_function` is.